# Question about dependency and peer dependency for my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Straight from the main Github repo for [React Chartjs wrapper](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2):

> As of 2.x we have made chart.js a peer dependency for greater flexibility. Please add chart.js as a dependency on your project to use 2.x. Currently, 2.5.x is the recommended version of chart.js to use.

I npm installed the library into my React app, automatically both `chart.js` and `react-chartjs-2` are now in my dependencies `package.json` file.

My question is based off of the quote above, do I now have to add the following field:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1"
  }
```

To my package.json file? Even if they are already both stated in my `dependencies`?

Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't have to. `react-chartjs-2` exposes `chart.js` as `peerDependency` to expose to you its dependency.

This way if there is another `chart.js` incompatible version (it may come from another package that also depends on `chart.js`) npm will warn you during installation process about it, therefore you can handle the inconsistency properly.

If `react-chartjs-2` haven't added it as `peerDependecy`, then you could face with different `chart.js` versions being installed, and it would may cause your application to crash.

To sum up, you would prefer to declare `peerDependecies` if you are building some plugin/library that it's expected to be consumed by others.